# Undefined class in 'path_provider' dependency for Flutter

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

After adding the path_provider dependency I'm running into problems around certain classes being undefined.'Directory' and 'File' are undefined, the problem occured after I tried to implement path_provider to my project in pubspec.yaml. This is needed to add a string to a text file on icon button press.

**Imports:**

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cryptick/data/crypto_data.dart';
import 'package:cryptick/modules/crypto_presenter.dart';
import 'package:shimmer/shimmer.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
```

**Code in question:**

```
ListTile _getListItemUi(Crypto currency, MaterialColor color) {
    return new ListTile(
      leading: new Image.network("http://cryptoicons.co/32@2x/color/"+currency.symbol.toLowerCase()+"@2x.png"),
      title: new Text(currency.name,
          style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      subtitle:
      _getSubtitleText(currency.price_usd, currency.percent_change_1h),
      isThreeLine: true,
      trailing: new IconButton(
        icon: new Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () async { Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
        new File('$appDocPath/my_file.txt').writeAsStringSync('myVar: $_currencies');  
        }
      ),
    );
  }
```

**These are the two lines showing the errors:**

```
onPressed: () async { Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
```

**And:**

```
new File('$appDocPath/my_file.txt').writeAsStringSync('myVar: $_currencies');
```

Comment: what exactly is your question ?? which class is undefined . and what is that code sample . you need to clearly state some things.

Comment: 'Directory' and 'File' are undefined, the problem occured after I tried to implement path_provider to my project in pubspec.yaml (needed to add a string to a text file on button press) I'll add this to my original question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Import this  and you are good to go :-

```
import 'dart:io';
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this hasn't made much of a difference as both classes are still undefined :/

Comment: could you tell which two lines are showing the error ??

Comment: check the original question as its been edited to reflect these two lines

Comment: Amazing, one note though is that its with a semi colon between 'dart' and 'io' and not a full stop

Comment: My bad  edited that . and not a semicolon but a colon .